# How to recover a corrupted Visual Studio c++ class diagram?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm looking into Visual Studio 2019 [Class Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects) to draw a diagram including mulitple classes in a package. I've noticed the only export format is Image and the .cd xml format contains absolute paths to the c++ class header files.

I've attempted to manually tweak the paths so they are relative and I now when I open a .cd file I get this:

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio error opening a .cd file. The text reads "Class diagrams are not supported by the project type. Add the class diagram file to a C#, VB or C++ project and try opening it again.]

I did sucessully move a .cd file from one computer to another by replacing the absolute paths prefixes, but it felt like a hacky workaround. I was hoping I can simply use relative paths.

Is there way to tweak the .xml so it's editable again ?
(I've tried undoing the changes, but that didn't solve the problem and I'm suspecting the UUIDs might have something to do with it, maybe?)

What's the recommended way of sharing a Visual Studio C++ class diagram for editing within a team ?

Comment: Did you try this: To display the contents of a project in a class diagram
In Solution Explorer or Class View, right-click the project and choose View, then choose View Class Diagram. An auto-populated Class Diagram is created.( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-view-existing-types?view=vs-2022#to-display-the-contents-of-a-project-in-a-class-diagram)

Comment: An assumption is that your relative paths have a wrong starting point. I'm not sure though if each path is resolved only once or perhaps more often with need for differing starting points.

Comment: @David Thank you for the advice. That is indeed how I am attempting to open the diagram, then I get greeted with error message above. As mentioned, this happens after I manually edited the .cd XML document to use relative paths instead of absolute paths. The issue is that after I restore the absolute paths, the error persists: the file remains corrupted

Comment: There must be some caching. Have encountered the same problem today in a completely different context. Perhaps you can rename the cd file and open then?

Comment: Interesting. I never considered caching. Where can I find more about this ? I have tried renaming the file but that didn't seem to work. Did that work for you ? (If so, what extension have you used ?)

Comment: Here you find the locations of different caches: https://errorhandlinginskills.wordpress.com/2018/07/28/how-to-clear-visual-studio-cache/. My own problem is too different, I neither use VS, nor I program in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience using relative paths isn't supported and (even absolute paths barely).

The only workaround I could think of is using a script to run wihin Visual Studio to run before openning the diagram on a new machine to detect the source code folder and alter the absolute paths accordingly.

In practice, this would be a nightmare under version control and using a completely separate diagramming tool and manually drawing the diagram is unfortunately the reality of the situation.
(I look forward to an alternative tool that can easily generate a class diagram that can be shared/edited within a team).